# NLog: How do I flush an AsyncTargetWrapper?

Tags: logging, nlog

The NLog documentation for AsyncTargetWrapper shows a call to wrapper.Flush(), with no arguments, after the sample is finished writing to the log.  But AsyncTargetWrapper's Flush() method requires an argument of type AsyncContinuation.  The documentation for that class says nothing about what it's for or how to use it.  I haven't been able to find an example of it, either.  Could someone please show me how Flush() should be used?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this in the [documentation](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v3.2.1/html/T_NLog_Common_AsyncContinuation.htm) and [source code](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/b518e925b40dc0e2e8bd5f97493831cb02a0c1bd/src/NLog/Common/AsyncContinuation.cs):

> **AsyncContinuation Delegate**
>
> Asynchronous continuation delegate - function invoked at the end of asynchronous processing.

Examples appear to be scarce, but you can find more info on how to use it [here](http://nlog-project.org/2010/05/09/asynchronous-logging-in-nlog-2-0.html).

Comment: Many thanks.  I'm not sure how useful this is for me now, since I do not fully understand the concept of asynchronous processing, and a solution using simpler threading may be better at this point.  But I have bookmarked this link for future reference.  I think this link is useful enough to be marked as an answer.